# Obtaining a solution to the renewal equation, when interarrival time is exponencial.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, convolution

A locally bounded solution $Z(t)$ to the renewal equation $ Z(t)=z(t)+\int^t_0Z(t-y)F(dy)$ is of the form $Z(t)=U*z(t)=\int^t_0z(t-u)U(du)$, where $U(t)$ is the renewal function (expected value of the number of renewal times until t).

If $F(x)=1-e^{-ax}$, for $x>0$, is the distribution of the interarrival times of a renewal process, we know that the renewal function is $U(t)=1+at$.

In Resnick's Adventures of Stochastic Processes, page 203, the author states that in this context $$U*z(t)=z(t)+a\int^t_0z(t-y)dy$$ Why is this?

Since, $U'(t)=a$, I would think that $U*z(t)=\int^t_0z(t-u)U(du)=a\int^t_0z(t-u) du$. Therefore substituting in the renewal equation one would get $U*z(t)=z(t)+F*U*z(t)$, but I have no idea how to obtain the equation in the book.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
Z &= z + Z*F = z + F*Z = z+F*(z+F*Z) \\
&= z+F*z + F_{2}*Z\\
&\vdots\\
&= z + z*\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{n}\\
&= z+z*m_{F}
\end{align*}$$

where $m_{F}(t) = \mathbb{E}[N(t)]$ where $N(t)$ is a poisson process with rate $a$ (because the interarrival times are exponential). Therefore, $m_{F}(t) = at$ and finally,

$$
Z(t) = z(t) + (z*at)(t) = z(t) + a \int_{0}^{t}z(t-y)dy
$$

P.S. Please comment if something is not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it. However, what was my mistake? was it the following equality $\int_0^tz(t-y)U(dy)=\int_0^tz(t-y)ady$? If so, what would be the correct one?

Comment: Now, I think that a straightforward solution would have been $U(t)*z(t) = (1+at)*z(t) = z(t) + ((at)*z)(t) = z(t) + a\int_{0}^{t}z(t-y)dy$. Yes that equation of yours is incorrect. What you are actually doing with that equation is $\int_{0}^{t}z(t-y)U'(y)dy \neq \int_{0}^{t}z(t-y)U(y)dy = z(t)*U(t)$. By the way, I never saw this notation $U(du)$ before and it is not clear whether you meant $dU(u)$ or $U(u)du$ with that. I believe that you wanted to convey the former meaning with that notation which isn't really correct for the formula of convolution.

Comment: By $U(du)$, I mean $dU(u)$. I thought that this notation was standard in measure/probability theory... thanks ;)