# How does the solution $U∗z(t)$ work for renewal equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, convolution, poisson-process

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552480/obtaining-a-solution-to-the-renewal-equation-when-interarrival-time-is-exponenc) discusses Example 3.5.4 in Resnick's book on page 203. However, when I try to understand the next example 3.5.5, I still have some doubts.

### Example 3.5.5

If $F(dx) = xe^{-x}dx$, then we have the following: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F^{n*}(dx)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2y}$$
In this case,
$$U*z(t)=z(t)+\int_0^tz(t-y)\{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2y}\}dy$$

### My Doubts

We know that 
\begin{align}
U(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F^{n*}(dx)\\
&= F^{0*}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}F^{n*}(dx)\\
&= 1+\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\Bigg)\\
&= \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}
\end{align}

By using the explanation from previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552480/obtaining-a-solution-to-the-renewal-equation-when-interarrival-time-is-exponenc):
\begin{align}
U(t) *z(t)&=\Bigg(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\Bigg)*z(t) \\
&= \frac{3}{2}*z(t) + \frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}*z(t) \\
&= \frac{3}{2}z(t) + \int_0^tz(t-y)\{-\frac{1}{2} d(e^{-2y}) \}\\
&= \frac{3}{2}z(t) + \int_0^tz(t-y)e^{-2y}dy 
\end{align}
Which is different from the textbook solution. What's wrong here?

Secondly, I am very confuse about the meaning of $F(dx)$
For example, in the definition of convolution, we have
$$F_1*F_2=\int_0^tF_2(t-x)F_1(dx)$$.

So $F(dx) = dF(x)$?